# Bash shell remove rows from a text file

Tags: bash, text, sed

i have a big domain lists file for a proxy filter. In another file I have some exceptions i would like to remove from filter file all rows of excpetions file. Is it possibile with some "sed" operation?

Thanks.

Comment: Please post some extract of the two files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can generally use `grep` with the `-v` and `-f` options for this. In fact, you probably want to use `fgrep` or the `-F` flag as well to ensure the string are considered as fixed string rather than regexes. Without that, for example, the first line of the `infile` file below will be removed despite not actually matching the fixed string.

`-v` reverses the sense that that matching lines are thrown away rather than kept, and `-f` will get the patterns from a file rather than the command line.

For example:

```
pax> cat infile
http://wwwxdodgy.com/rest-of-url
http://www.dodgy.com/rest-of-url
ftp://this/one/is/good
https://www.bad.org/rest-of-url

pax> cat exceptions 
http://www.dodgy.com
https://www.bad.org

pax> fgrep -v -f exceptions infile 
ftp://this/one/is/good
```

Answer (score 2):

It is easier to do this with grep:

```
grep -v -x -F -f /path/to/exclude /path/to/file
```